# SQL Server: Let user create/modify new views, but not alter existing

Tags: sql-server, schema, roles, sql-server-2008-r2

We would like to let users create their own custom views but don't want to let them modify any existing tables or views.  I am pretty green regarding the administration capabilities of SQL Server, but I assume this is a common scenario.

I was thinking the best route to do this would be to create a new schema to contain these views, and then only let the user have control over this schema.  Is this reasonable?

The issue is I don't actually know the mechanics to do this.  I created the schema, and I tried to create a role for this schema, but its not 'clicking' in my mind.

Comment: Probably not meant to be tagged sql-server-200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of SQL Server you're using?  But in 2008, Open SQL Server Management Studio.  Create a new procedure, and add this code:

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW ON SCHEMA :: your_schema TO user_role
```

I think that should work...?  I only use SQL Server now and then.  You might have to give them ALTER, SELECT, etc. as well.

Comment: 2008 R2 Express to be exact ... lemme try that out

Comment: According to BOL, "Requires CREATE VIEW permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the view is being created.
" are the permissions required for create view.

Comment: Things are clicking now.  As Ben pointed out I couldn't get 'CREATE VIEW' to work on a schema level but was able to work out that we have two levels to work on ... Database and Schema.  I got a simple example working and I think I might actually understand why :p  thanks all